# MySQL Delete using subquery on same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery, inner-join, sql-delete

Using the following query, I am able to return the results I need.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM lms_attendance t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
             FROM lms_attendance t2
             WHERE t2.user = t1.user            
             ORDER BY t2.id DESC
             LIMIT 1)
```

However, when trying to do a DELETE instead, this does not work. Through trial and error, I either get `unknown column` or `can't specify target updated in from clause`. The main issue here is that I absolutely have to have the WHERE clause as it is so that it returns the maximum id for each user, and not for the entire table.

Comment: So you want to retain only those maximum id per user?

Comment: Correct. I'm trying to retain only the max <field> per user, while deleting the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Try this query below.  Please run a select first to confirm if it is the correct records before running the delete. Better if you keep a backup table too.

Run select:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM lms_attendance t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(id) id
           FROM lms_attendance
           GROUP BY user) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

If looks OK;

```
DELETE t1.* FROM lms_attendance t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(id) id
           FROM lms_attendance
           GROUP BY user) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```